# ggplot2 - Add labels to second graph with secondary axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to add labels to both the red line on the graph and the columns.
I managed to add labels either to the columns or the line but I am not able to do both at the same time.

Can anyone help?

**Test Dataframe**

```
           ebit ebit_margin year
Company1    2421    0.054   2019    
Company1.1  1928    0.049   2018    
Company1.2  1915    0.050   2017    
Company1.3  2135    0.060   2016    
Company1.4  1534    0.041   2015
```

**Data**

```
test <- structure(list(ebit = c(2421.459, 1928.349, 
1914.744, 2134.6, 1534.048), ebit_margin = c(0.05367, 0.04859, 
0.04973, 0.06016, 0.04143), year = structure(5:1, .Label = c("2015", 
"2016", "2017", "2018", "2019"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Company1", 
"Company1", "Company1", "Company1", 
"Company1"))
```

**Code**

```
scaleFactor <- max(test$ebit) / max(test$ebit_margin)

ggplot(test, aes(as.factor(year), ebit, label=test$ebit)) + 
  geom_col(width = 0.5, fill = "darkblue", alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(aes(as.factor(year), ebit_margin * scaleFactor, group = 1),  size = 1,  col = "red", alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "EBIT Value", sec.axis = sec_axis(~./scaleFactor, name = "EBIT Margin", labels = function(b) { paste0(round(b * 100, 3), "%")})) +
  #geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) + 
  theme_bw()  +
  labs(title = "Key Financials Across Years",
       subtitle = "Earnings Before Interest and Taxation",
       x = "Year") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1)) +
  geom_label(
    label = c(test$ebit),
    position = position_stack(vjust = 0.75),
    check_overlap = T
  )
```

What I managed to get so far is the following:

[image: Current Outcome]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a second `geom_label` with the appropriate `y` and `label` aesthetic:

```
ggplot(test, aes(as.factor(year), ebit, label=test$ebit)) + 
  geom_col(width = 0.5, fill = "darkblue", alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(aes(as.factor(year), ebit_margin * scaleFactor, group = 1),  
            size = 1, col = "red", alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "EBIT Value", 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~./scaleFactor, 
                     name = "EBIT Margin", 
                     labels = function(b) { 
                       paste0(round(b * 100, 3), "%")})) +
  theme_bw()  +
  labs(title = "Key Financials Across Years",
       subtitle = "Earnings Before Interest and Taxation",
       x = "Year") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1)) +
  geom_label(
    aes(label = ebit),
    position = position_stack(vjust = 0.75),
    check_overlap = T
  ) +
  geom_label(
    aes(label = ebit_margin * 100, y = ebit_margin * scaleFactor),
    colour = "red"
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

just add

```r
  geom_label(
    aes(as.factor(year), ebit_margin * scaleFactor, group = 1),
    label = c(test$ebit),
    position = position_stack(vjust = 0.99),
    check_overlap = T
  )
```

So ur result will be

```r
ggplot(test, aes(as.factor(year), ebit, label=test$ebit)) + 
  geom_col(width = 0.5, fill = "darkblue", alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(aes(as.factor(year), ebit_margin * scaleFactor, group = 1),  size = 1,  col = "red", alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "EBIT Value", sec.axis = sec_axis(~./scaleFactor, name = "EBIT Margin", labels = function(b) { paste0(round(b * 100, 3), "%")})) +
  #geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) + 
  theme_bw()  +
  labs(title = "Key Financials Across Years",
       subtitle = "Earnings Before Interest and Taxation",
       x = "Year") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1)) +
  geom_label(
    label = c(test$ebit),
    position = position_stack(vjust = 0.75),
    check_overlap = T
  )+
  geom_label(
    aes(as.factor(year), ebit_margin * scaleFactor, group = 1),
    label = c(test$ebit),
    position = position_stack(vjust = 0.99),
    check_overlap = T
  )
```